# if there is a possibility to split the author.php in wordpress in several subcategories?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have created a ajax menu in the author.php in wordpress. There one can select certain menus. The whole one also functions so far, besides, the problem is only that the information about the user are only visible in the Author.php. The problem is that other php files have nobody accessed to the Informations from the author.php.

Now my question is,whether is there a possibility  to split the author.php in sub categories(sub menus). Nevertheless, also the have access to information which in the author.php. For example, such functions they contain the user name or the user description.

already once thanks for answers

Fabian

ps : Sorry for my bad english